# Laravel group by, with relationship in different tables

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel eloquent, trying to fetch information contained in different tables and compare them.

My tables are

```
tbl_checks
    id,check_id, person_id //person_id is the foreign key

tbl_persons
   id, category,
```

I would like to fetch all people in table `tbl_checks` and group the data by person category `tbl_persons.category`.

In normal SQL statement it's like:

```
select from tbl_checks group by tbl_person.category where the tbl_persons.id is contained in tbl_checks.person_id
```

In my models I have:

```
class PersonsModel extends Model {
    //connect to the next database
    protected $connection = 'inspection';
    protected $table = 'tbl_trucks';

    //relation with tbl_checks

    public function checks(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\TblChecks','person_id','id');
    }
}
```

How can I use the ELoquent model, and not the Db facade?
To make it abit clear.
Am trying to find all persons who are in the table_checks and ignore persons id who are not in tbl_checks

Comment: @Webinion The answer youve produced doesnt have an extra query to the related table, Am trying to get all persons contained in tbl_checks and ignore those that are not there and then get totals of those who are contained and group by person.category

Answer (score 21):

Assuming you have a `person` relationship in your `TblChecks` model:

```
TblChecks::with('person')->get()->groupBy('person.category');
```

Comment: now am getting an error Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Comment: now am getting an error Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Comment: Please post the whole error message.

Comment: Try setting the value of `strict` to `false` in `config/database.php`

Comment: now after setting to false am getting a new error of Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::get()

Comment: Please post the `person` relationship. Did you exactly copy my code?

Comment: Thank you so much, you save me !

Comment: This is the real solution.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `Laravel >= 5.3`, use `Eloquent::has` ([Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)):

```
$persons = PersonsModel::has('checks')->get();
```

For `Laravel < 5.3`, use [Where Exists Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-exists-clauses):

```
$persons = PersonsModel::whereExists(function ($q) {
    $q->select(DB::raw(1))->from('tbl_checks')
        ->whereRaw('tbl_persons.id=tbl_checks. person_id');
})->get();
```

Comment: Not sure your versions are correct; `has()` and `whereHas()` are both working fine on my `"laravel/framework": "5.0.*",` project.